"Downloading external resources is disabled." - While generating TestNG xml file in Maven
I am learning Selenium and TestNG framework, while doing so, I generated a xml file in TestNG framework, but getting in suggestion - "Downloading external resources is disabled."
Updated TestNG Plugin from Eclipse marketplace
POM Xml file is having necessary dependencies of TestNG framework

Please edit your question and some additional context. Perhaps a screenshot or stacktrace of where you are seeing this would help get more information and help others solve your question.
